# need only sign displayed at a region

Tags: c#, angularjs

How do you get done so, then it is only a radio as display the text when you have that value. That is to say that there will always be only one being shown. and it must not be shown to the other.

[image]

The where I add the red box to the text which is displayed only be used the place. while elsewhere shows not disclosed.

```
<span ng-show="PakkeValue.UserCount >= 1">Du får ekstra profil - {{PakkeValue.UserCount}} stk.</span>
```

EIDT update:

```
<div class="form-group">
@foreach (var item in Model.listpric)
{
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input name="Pakke1"
                type="radio"
                ng-model="PakkeValue"
                ng-value="{ 
                IdPakke: '@item.id', 
                Months: '@item.mdr', 
                Price: '@item.pristal', 
                UserCount: '@item.UserCount'}" />
        @item.mdr måned(er) (@item.pristal,- kr./md) <span ng-show="PakkeValue.UserCount >= 1">Du får ekstra profil - {{PakkeValue.UserCount}} stk.</span>
    </div>
}
</div>
```

Comment: you need to post your radio button code as well, your question is not clear by its own @Jasper

Comment: i have update @Yaser

Comment: @Jasper is this google translate? I dont understand you.

Comment: I see your problem, you are using PakkeValue to show or hide the span, that is equal for all of the radio's. You have to use something which is unique to an individual radio or move your span outside of the loop @Jasper

Comment: Thanks @Yaser ! so nice u will help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your problem, you are using PakkeValue to show or hide the span, that is equal for all of the radio's. You have to use something which is unique to an individual radio or move your span outside of the loop:

Below is the version which checks both the user count and price to show it only in one of them. You can use any other unique value.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @foreach (var item in Model.listpric)
    {
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input name="Pakke1"
                    type="radio"
                    ng-model="PakkeValue"
                    ng-value="{ 
                    IdPakke: '@item.id', 
                    Months: '@item.mdr', 
                    Price: '@item.pristal', 
                    UserCount: '@item.UserCount'}" />
            @item.mdr måned(er) (@item.pristal,- kr./md) 
            <span ng-show="PakkeValue.UserCount >= 1 && PakkeValue.Price == @item.pristal">Du får ekstra profil - {{PakkeValue.UserCount}} stk.</span>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```